# How can we get the objects in reverse order from list object?

Tags: java, collections

in my List object(of generic type of pojo class objects) i am getting that list by calling service method, as per my requirement i have to place those object values in reverse order, for example

```
List<MyPojo> listData = serviceObj.getTableDate();//gets the total content of table
if(listData.size()>0){
  int i=0;
  while(i>=listData.size()){
    listData.get(i).getPojoId();
    listData.get(i).getPojoName();
  }
}
```

Note: please dont tell to me use iterator or to use ListIterator, because i am showing the data in Grid(JQuery) some logic will fail while using iterator, the code what written was just sample of few lines only.

Comment: You've rejected the obvious solution, but just saying "some logic will fail" doesn't tell us *why* you've rejected it really. Oh, and your sample code is completely broken - you're never changing `i`, and your condition is basically saying, "If calling `get(i)` will throw an exception... let's call it!"

Comment: First of all you code snippet will run into an endless loop. Then I don't really unterstand what you want to do.

Comment: sorry i am forget to keep one in code snippet that i++ before closing the while loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would `Collections.reverse(list)` work?

Comment: i will not work, it raises java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mypack.MyPojo cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable............. Exception

Comment: @Naresh - unlikely. This method does not require elements to be comparable. You are probably calling another method.

Comment: @Naresh Are you sure you are using reverse, and not accidentally using maybe sort?

Answer (score 0):

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has `Iterables.reverse(List)`, which returns a reversed view of the original list without modifying it.